# How to get all objects from many to many relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So i have 2 models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    """Artist model."""
    name = models.CharField('Artist name', max_length=255)
    genre = models.CharField('Music genre', max_length=255)
```

```
class Event(models.Model):
    """Event model."""
    name = models.CharField('Event name', max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    localization_name = models.CharField('Localization name', max_length=255)
    longitude = models.FloatField('Longitude', default=0.0)
    latitude = models.FloatField('Latitude', default=0.0)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, verbose_name='Artists')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')
```

And i need to get for one artist, every other artist that was with him on events.
I made this on Artist model:

```
    @property
    def get_participate_artists(self):
        return list(self.event_set.all().values_list('artists__event__artists__name', 'artists__event__artists__genre', named=True).distinct())
```

but i wanna get queryset or list of Artist objects.

Comment: Do you mean all artists that were part of all events or one specific event?

Comment: All artists of all events.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get one artist
first_artist = Artist.objects.first()

# get events where the artist was present
events = Event.objects.filter(artists__in=first_artist)

# create list containing all OTHER artist objects from those events
other_artists = []

for event in events:
    for artist in event.artists:
        if artist.id != first_artist.id:
            other_artists.append(artist)
        else:
            pass
```

Might have some duplicates but you can handle those accordingly.